# How do I pass values with a link to a new page?

Tags: php, mysql

What I want is to be able to click on the link (review.php) and then to display the review corresponding to that film only, on a new page.

Not sure if my MySQL query is wrong or if my A href link is not formatted correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
require_once('./includes/mysql_connect.php');

$query = "SELECT films.movie_title, films.rating, films.actor, reviewed.review
          FROM films
          INNER JOIN reviewed
          ON films.movie_id=reviewed.review_id";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Could not execute mysql" . mysql_error()); // Run Query

$num = mysql_numrows($result);

if ($num > 0) { // If it ran ok, display records.

    echo "<p> There are curently $num records.</p>";

    // Table header.
     echo '<table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
    <td align="left"><b>Movie Title</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b>Leading Actor</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b>Rating</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b>Review</b></td>
    </tr>';

    // Fetch and print all the records.
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<tr>
        <td align="left">' . $row['movie_title'] . '</td>
        <td align="left">' . $row['actor'] . '</td>
        <td align="left">' . $row['rating'] . '</td>
        <td align="left"><a href="review.php?id='. $row['review'] .  '> Read Review </a>
        </tr> ';
    }


}

?>
```

Comment: by passing parameter in url (GET) and you are doing what's the problem. And there is a typo in your code link should be like `href="review.php?id='. $row['review'] .  '">`

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated, use _fetch_assoc instead of _fetch_array. What is this? mysql_numrows ? where are ending doublequotes '. $row['review'] .  '>  ? and add target="_blank" to open link on a new page

Comment: You are not closing the last <td> on the last line

Comment: How do I know go about of display the review on the new page ?